# How to "transfer" indices from dot product to metric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

In [this source](http://www.physics.mcgill.ca/~andrzej/Peskin/Chap9.pdf), the author (Andrzej Pokraka, Solutions to problems from Peskin & Schroeder) is computing an integral related to scalar QED. In the step where the equation is labelled (29), the author is changing the expression $l_\mu l_\nu$ to $\frac{1}{d} g_{\mu\nu} l^2$ (where $d$ is the spacetime dimensions). How can you do that? I have tried playing with the indices, but I don't see yet a way to transfer indices from the metric to the $l$'s.

Comment: Maybe it is not that $l_{\mu} l_{\nu} = \frac{1}{d} g_{\mu \nu} l^2$, but rather $\int l_{\mu} l_{\nu} = \int  \frac{1}{d} g_{\mu \nu} l^2$ ?

Comment: There’s the rest of that sentence top of the next pages that says they dropped terms. Trace of the metric will give you the part proportional to $d$.

Comment: @Brick Yes they dropped terms linear in $l$, but isn't that referring to the previous steps?

Comment: @MBolin Mm that sounds quite plausible. I am starring at it with the integral now, and I am still stuck though.

Comment: @Jxx I am quite sure that's what happens. See eg. equation (10.79) in http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/~ajd268/Notes/UsefulFormulas.pdf. I can't give an explanation right now though. But at least you can check that if you contract with $g_{\mu \nu}$ you get the same thing on both sides.

Comment: @MBolin Thanks for the link, they mention indeed that this is related to the symmetry of the integral. Still not sure how to derive it properly though.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.04549.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the integral is a rank-2 Lorentz tensor that depends only on the Lorentz scalar $q^2$. This means that it is a rank-2 *isotropic* Lorentz tensor; i.e., none of its components change under Lorentz transformations. The Lorentz group has only two fundamental isotropic tensors: $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\lambda}$. All others are built from these. Thus the integral must be proportional to $g_{\mu\nu}$ and the constant of proportionality is found by contracting.

This is the Minkowski-space analog of the Euclidean-space integration of products of unit vectors over all angles, such as

$$\int d\Omega\,n_i n_j \propto \delta_{ij},$$

$$\int d\Omega\,n_i n_j n_k n_l \propto \delta_{ij}\delta_{kl} + \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} + \delta_{il}\delta_{jk},$$

etc.